Relation between uniformly absolutely continuous and absolutely continuous in measure theory
I'm a little confused with these two definitions:
Definition of $\textbf{absolutely continuous}$:

$\nu$ is said absolutely continuous in respect to $\mu$ if $\mu(E)=0 \Rightarrow \nu(E)=0, \forall E \in \mathscr{F}$.

Definition of $\textbf{uniformly absolutely continuous}$:

A family of functions {$\nu_\alpha$ : $\alpha \in I$} is said uniformly absolutely continuous if:$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 : \forall E \in \mathscr{F}, \quad \mu(E) < \delta \Rightarrow  \sup_{\alpha \in I} \nu_\alpha(E) \leq \epsilon $$

I can see that if I take $|I| = 1$, I will have uniformly absolutely continuous $\Rightarrow$ absolutely continuous.
Is the converse true? Is there any equivalence since both definitions have the "absolutely continuous" in them.
Thank you in advance.

See this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) and in particular the section (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity)

Let $\mu\nu: d\mu=dx, d\nu=(|x|+1)dx$. Then the two functions share the same null sets (i.e. the null sets wrt $dx$). In particular, $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. However, for $\varepsilon=1$ there exists no $\delta$ that satisfies the definition of uniform absolute continuity wrt $\mu$ for $\nu$. To see this, let $A_n=[n,n+1/\sqrt n]$. For any $\delta>0$ there exists $n$ big enough such that $\mu(A_n)<\delta$. However, as $\nu(A_n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, so $\nu$ is not uniformly absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$.
If you assume both measures to be finite, the result is true and it follows from Radon-Nykodim.
